# What is the proper way to update the time enroute in an EFB system without the assistance of any GPS technology?

Tags: faa, efb

I remember training with paper nav logs and the student would have to update the actual ground speed based on time between two waypoints in a flight.

In an EFB, what is considered the proper way to do this per FAA standards?

Does the student need to e-mail and print the automatically-generated navigation log, and use it in a paper form with an E6-B flight computer along the route of flight?

If they *are* using GPS, does that suffice for ensuring they're staying updated as long as they calculated expected fuel burn at each waypoint based on GPS-indicated ground speed?

The software we use is ForeFlight, but surely this question is not limited to ForeFlight alone.

Comment: If you have foreflight connected to a GPS receiver or use the internal GPS (if available) this information is updated for you within foreflight.